# How do I hide these Windows 11 Icons?

Tags: windows, windows-11

These Icons are in the lower right part of the screen.

They are

- Wifi
- Battery
- and Windows Security

[image: Icons that I want to hide]

Comment: I believe W11 is similar to W10 in this regard and there is a page in Settings for doing this, probably accessed easily by right-clicking on the tray area. What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried?

Comment: WInkey - type "Settings" - Enter - type "Tray icons" - Click "Control which system tray icons appear in the taskbar". Click "Other system tray icons"

Comment: Or.. right click taskbar -> settings -> "other system tray icons"

Comment: They are useful icons and Apps.  Just hide them and you will not see them.